# Ban IP by hostname?

Tags: .htaccess, http, ip, hostname

Any way to deny access to our site via the hostname an IP resolves to?

For example:
109.163.233.200 resolves to wau.torservers.net , and we don't want anyone access our site with a hostname that resolves to this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Having to do a reverse dns lookup per every request would be very expensive.

Comment: what *very expensive* can that be?

Comment: I found this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html - You mean resource expensive?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to do it with `.htaccess` (which I don't know if it supports what you want), as the tag might indicate, and if you have root access on the (non-Windows) server box, you can add the hostname to `/etc/hosts.deny`. Let me quote it, here on Debian, as it is self-documenting:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts.deny 
# /etc/hosts.deny: list of hosts that are _not_ allowed to access the system.
#                  See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: some.host.name, .some.domain
#             ALL EXCEPT in.fingerd: other.host.name, .other.domain
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "portmap" for the
# daemon name. Remember that you can only use the keyword "ALL" and IP
# addresses (NOT host or domain names) for the portmapper, as well as for
# rpc.mountd (the NFS mount daemon). See portmap(8) and rpc.mountd(8)
# for further information.
#
# The PARANOID wildcard matches any host whose name does not match its
# address.
#
# You may wish to enable this to ensure any programs that don't
# validate looked up hostnames still leave understandable logs. In past
# versions of Debian this has been the default.
# ALL: PARANOID
```

For more, see the [hosts.deny man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts.deny)